# Before I ask a question the similar posts suggestions do not scroll properly

Tags: bug, asking-questions, firefox

I started to post my first post and was offered similar posts, but when I scrolled, I saw this problem in Firefox. The text is scrolling behind the original text that I saw.

[image: The text is scrolling behind the original test I see/saw]

There's no no preview button I can see, so now I am kind of typing blind, and I am not sure you will see what I saw and posted.

Comment: If you have Chromium or Chrome installed please try it in a different web browser and comment if the same problem is reproducible in a different web browser.

Comment: It looks like you've made alterations to the default user interface. Can you disable these alterations and see if it resolves the problem?

Comment: (ok this is weird - as in how my reply is being shown when I type it)
Using Chrome it works as expected.
Thanks to both for the replies.

Comment: > It looks like you've made alterations to the default user interface
As far as I know I have only really changed the theme/colour scheme.

Comment: I've had this issue using FF for some time. I simply check the up-arrow to close the suggestions and then re-open with the down arrow and all is fine. I haven't made any changes to the user interface that I can think of since installing 18.04 a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 6):

Same problem here. The bug has already been [reported on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340329/stack-overflow-duplicated-layer-bug), with many confirmations. Hopefully this will get fixed some time soon.

Workarounds include:

- clicking any of the links offered (they open in new tabs) - scrolling gets fixed
- pressing the up arrow to close the suggestions and reopening them with the down arrow
- using a different browser to Firefox

Sorry for the inconvenience!